# Mysql data automatically reverts back

Tags: mysql

Everytime I update and insert data in my mysql database it gets reverted back after few minutes

I did a test and update some data on our database  , all went well there were no errors but after a few minutes the data that I updated suddenly reverted back to its old data

I really need your help . I think inserts are also affected. We are losing data .

===============

## my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=268435456
innodb_file_per_table=1
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time=4
tmpdir=/var/lib/mysql/mysqltempdir/
```

Comment: Declare a commit after the insert query

Comment: yes I did .... infact , I did a test and also update the data using phpmyadmin provided by cpanel ... I dont know where to begin... the code looks fine too .. I ran the test and it passed in my local machine ...

Comment: Would b glad if u provide the code

Comment: I used the phpmyadmin ... I just did a simple update..you know , the typical mysql update command .

Comment: Use mysql_begin_transaction and mysql_commit functions